# How to configure or disable Linux click-and-drag selection feature?

Tags: linux, xorg, mouse, input, drag-and-drop

Linux has this specific feature where dropdown menus are opened on a click and the mouse button can be held down, dragged and released on the wanted menu option to select it without having to click and release twice.

I am unsure where this feature originates, but is there a way to configure or modify it?

My problem is that, while some desktop environments like GNOME and KDE do not have classic dropdown menus on their panel, more traditional ones, such as Xfce and MATE do open dropdown menus for some panel items.

It's happened to me a couple of times that I've accidentally closed a program by its notification icon, because I only wanted to open the menu and held down the mouse button a little to long or moved the pointer unconsciously by a few pixels before releasing, causing me to select "Quit" in the menu, without even seeing it.

Is there either a way to disable this behaviour completely or configure it so that the pointer has to be moved a few more pixels in order to trigger a selection upon mouse button release?

I already tried to change the drag-and-drop distance in the mouse settings, but that only changes the distance when dragging files, not inside of menus.

Comment: Have you found a solution?